# Use lemmas without numbering, without separate thing in preamble for each lemma

Tags: numbering, theorems

My apologies if this question is answered elsewhere; I searched for it with no success.

I want to use lemmas in my paper, but I want to do it the dummy way: instead of inserting a different thing in the preamble for each lemma, I just want to use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
Here is my first lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Here is the first proof \& \qedhere 
\end{proof}

\begin{lemma}
Here is my second lemma
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Here is the second proof \& \qedhere 
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

but then it will automatically insert a number. This is just a homework assignment, so I have no need of a number for each lemma. Is there a simple way to get rid of the numbering? I've tried putting asterisks in various places...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `*` form of the definition

```
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I notice actually that the qed symbol will be put in automatically, so I don't need '\qedhere'. What is the difference between putting `&&` and `\&`, as you edited?